# Import Error: No module named spiders

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following directory tree and I'm trying to import `models` in `my_spider.py`:

```
.
├── my_spider
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── my_spider.py
│       ├── my_spider.pyc
│       └── models.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

In `my_spider.py`, I have:

`from my_spider.spiders import models`

I get an error saying `ImportError: No module named spiders`. I must be doing something very basic wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `my_spider.py` and `models.py` are in the same directory, I think you should just use `import models`

Comment: Sure. But if I were to give a 'full' path, how should it be done?

Comment: @Kate You can't have both called `my_spider`. Change either the package name or the module name.